# rewrite and replace value of a get param inside url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

original address - `example.com/index.php?c=bs`
or without `index.php` - i.e. just - `example.com/?c=bs`

what I want in address bar - `example.com/blue-sky`

here is my try - without success:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?c=bs [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ ?c=blue-sky [L,QSA]
```

pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I want in address bar - `example.com/blue-sky`

Assuming you have already changed your internal links to this desired *canonical* URL then you can implement the following in `.htaccess` to externally redirect `/index.php?c=bs` (or `/?c=bs`) to `/blue-sky` for the benefit of SEO. Followed by a rewrite to internally rewrite requests for `/blue-sky` back to `/index.php?c=bs`.

For example (assuming you are on Apache 2.4):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "/index.php?c=bs" (or "/?c=bs") to "/blue-sky"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=bs$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /blue-sky [QSD,R=301,L]

# Rewrite (internally) "/blue-sky" back to "/index.php?c=bs"
RewriteRule ^blue-sky$ index.php?c=bs [QSA,END]
```

The `QSD` flag on the first rule is required to discard the original query string (ie. `c=bs`) from the redirect response. Otherwise, it will redirect to `/blue-sky?c=bs`. This requires Apache 2.4

The `QSA` flag on the second rule allows any additional query string parameters that might be present on the initial request being appended. eg. `/blue-sky?foo=1` would be rewritten to `index.php?c=bs&foo=1`. If that is not required and you are not expecting any additional query string then remove the `QSA` flag.

The `END` flag (as opposed to `L`) prevents any further loops by the rewrite engine and thus prevents the rewritten URL being redirected back to the canonical URL (which would otherwise result in an endless redirect loop). The `END` flag requires Apache 2.4.

---

A look at your directives:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?c=bs [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]
> RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ ?c=blue-sky [L,QSA]
> ```

The first rule would essentially redirect `/<anything>?c=bs` back to the document root, except that the `%1` backreference is *empty* and without a `RewriteBase` directive, this will result in a malformed redirect, exposing the absolute filesystem directory.

The second rule rewrites `/<anything>` to `?c=blue-sky`, which should presuambly be `c=bs` (but that would result in a redirect loop since the rewrite engine starts over with the use of `L`, rather than `END`).

Comment: you should write a complete and step by step tutorial somewhere. There is no such a thing on the entire web. Thanks a lot.